# java System.in How can I use System.in.read()

Tags: java, for-loop, system.in

I am  new in java.

I should use System.in.read() to solve my program

but I don't know ,what does it exactly do?

thanks for helping

> my question :
>
> take a number of user. If the number is less than 1,
>    print an error.
>    Otherwise, print the result of 2 ^ ( 1 incoming number ) . 
>     "Once with for  AND  Once with while "

```
'int i ; 
int  num ;
System.out.println("enter a number : ");
for (i=1 ; (num = System.in.read()) != '\r' ; i++  ) 
{

  if( num <1 )
  {
  System.out.println("illegal value! \n enter a number"); 
  }

      else
      {
        int j; int pow = 1;
        for (j = 1 ; j <= num ; j++) 
        {
          pow *=2 ;
          System.out.println(pow);
        }

  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Please, Enter:");
    BufferedReader consoleIn =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String stringInt = consoleIn.readLine();
    int fromConsoleInput = Integer.parseInt(stringInt);
```

Comment: question : take a number of user. If the number is less than 1,
     * print an error. Otherwise, print the result of 2 ^ ( 1 incoming number ) . 
     * Once with for  AND  Once with while

Comment: My code : int i ; 
    int  num ;
    System.out.println("enter a number : ");
    for (i=1 ; (num = System.in.read()) != '\r' ; i++  ) 
    {
    
      if( num <1 )
      {
      System.out.println("illegal value! \n enter a number"); 
      }
      
          else
          {
            int j; int pow = 1;
            for (j = 1 ; j <= num ; j++) 
            {
              pow *=2 ;
              System.out.println(pow);
            }
       
      }
    }